# Компонент WPF (Silverlight) фотопанорама 360

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, 3d

Для меня стал неожиданностью тот факт, что я в интернете не нашел НИ ОДНОГО компонента на C# для панорам. Есть небольшая наработка на Codeplex для Silverlight, но это всего лишь наработка, тогда как на Flash все давно уже есть! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где найти такой компонент C# или как создать свой (знание 3D имеются).

З.Ы. Надо переходить на флеш или можно обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

Готовый компонент не найден. Но есть заготовки.

[How to: Create a Panorama Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941109(v=vs.92).aspx)

> This topic will show you how to create a panorama application in Windows Phone. For a panorama sample, see Code Samples for Windows Phone.

[F# and C# Win Phone Panorama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e70ea3a-c564-4199-8915-b651a0035bbe)

> This is a F# template that generates a Windows Phone 7 panorama application (Silverlight) that utilizes the power of Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: это не панорама для обзора в точке снимка, а простая панель в WP7. Это 2 разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаток панорам и не очень понял чем не подходит "наработка" на `codeplex` и чего там катастрофически не хватает в отличии от флеша?

[HD View](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/hdview/).

[About HD View SL](http://hdviewsl.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Спасибо, но это не панорамы, а пример использования DeepZoom.

Answer (score 0):

После проведения поисков я обнаружил сырой проект 2006 года на Silverlight (2) ([codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com)) который никак не годится для панорам. Отставание в развитии Silverlight по сравнению с Flash очевидно на примере. В общем ничего сложного не составляет создать в WPF или Silverlight5 3D сферу, наложить на нее текстуру, что я и сделал в течении пару часов. Но как система для высокого качества изображений нужен комплексный проект (при высоком качестве панорамного снимка налаживаемая текстура потребляет очень много памяти). Проще (но лучше ли?) использовать уже готовую Flash [систему](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Farcsoft-panorama-maker.en.softonic.com%2F&ei=lGhjUObwNZLV4QSg0YC4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFrYj3xuK2sa2GJpZ7EYBOuOru4mw&sig2=L_rj8VTNkhtsYOOL5gbruA)